# PHP regex problem, can't get it right

Tags: php, regex

I am having a problem with Regex (yes, again, one day I have to sit and read about it).
Here is the code I'm using;

```
$string = "[if-protectDelete-{0}-][data]name[/data] can be deleted[/elseif][elseif-{1}-][data]name[/data] can't be deleted[/elseif][elseif-{2}-]No data[/elseif][/endif]";

if (preg_match_all("#\[elseif-\{(.+)\}-\](.+?)\[/elseif\]#", $string, $matches)) {
                        dumper($matches[0]);
                    }
```

$matches[0] output is;

```
array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(75) "[elseif-{1}-]PHP REGEX can't be deleted[/elseif][elseif-{2}-]No data[/elseif]"
}
```

I can get the part right for if, but elseif... It is totally different scenario I guess.
Shouldn't it out put like this? ;

```
array {
[0] => "[elseif-{1}-]PHP REGEX can't be deleted[/elseif]",
[1] => "[elseif-{2}-]No data[/elseif]"
}
```

I will be glad if anyone could help me out with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add ?

```
your : \[elseif-\{(.+)\}-\](.+?)\[/elseif\]
right: \[elseif-\{(.+?)\}-\](.+?)\[/elseif\]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you still have a greedy `+` in there. This might fix it:

```
#\[elseif-\{([0-9]+)\}-\](.+?)\[/elseif\]#
```

Notice the `[0-9]+` that replaces the `.+`. Let me know how that goes.

---

Assuming you might have anything inside the curly braces, except other curly breaces, this would be even better:

```
#\[elseif-\{([^}]+)\}-\](.+?)\[/elseif\]#
```

Or, like you mentioned: `.+?`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. (.+?) This version is much better cos I might be using number or I might be using letters. I'm just trying to get some php codes going in a string for my Jquery Data Table. I found such parsing data like BBCode to do some PHP actions would be nice and make my life easier.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here, I didn't notice your comment before. Once I get enough rep, I will vote for your answer. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `dumper` do but the array `$matches` contains the whole matching in `$matches[0]` and the groups captured in `$matches[1]` `$matches[2]` ...

so you should do : `print_r($matches);` to get your matches groups.

Comment: dumper () is my function to dump variables. If I use it dumper($matches, TRUE), then it is the same as print_r($matches). If I use dumper($matches) the same as var_dump($matches). Only difference, I don't have to echo "<pre>" and "</pre>" each time I want to output an array.